# Using document.classlist.remove in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, dom-manipulation

When I click on a new li tag, I want the classname to change to active (which works), but also remove active from the rest of the li tags (which doesn't work). document.getElementByTagName('li').classList.remove="active", doesn't work because it is saying it is not defined. Should I go about this a different way... maybe storing something different in the state?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Anime.css';

function Anime(){
    const [currentCase, setCurrentCase] = useState(0)
    function getAnime(){
        fetch('https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    }

    function currentSelector(e){
        document.getElementsByTagName('li').clasList.remove("active");
        setCurrentCase(e.target.value)
        e.target.className = "active" 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAnime();
      }, []);
    
    return(
        <div className="anime">
            {/* Selectors */}
            <ul>
                <li value= {0} className="active" onClick={currentSelector}>Trending</li>
                <li value={1} onClick={currentSelector}>Action</li>
                <li value={2} onClick={currentSelector}>Adventure</li>
                <li value={3} onClick={currentSelector}>Comedy</li>
                <li value={4} onClick={currentSelector}>Drama</li>
                <li value={5} onClick={currentSelector}>Magic</li>
                <li value={6} onClick={currentSelector}>Romance</li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Anime
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo `clasList` should have 2 "s"s.  Please compare in the code snippet you provided.  Additionally, why are you using the regular DOM API instead of dealing with this in React's APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the usual DOM API for things like this in React, instead use React's state management and conditional rendering functionality. You already have a state variable to track the active case (`currentCase`), so you can just set the class name conditionally while rendering.

For each `li`, just check if the value of `currentCase` matches the value for that `li` and if so, give that `li` the class `active`, otherwise give a different class.

For example:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Anime.css';

function Anime(){
    const [currentCase, setCurrentCase] = useState(0)
    function getAnime(){
        fetch('https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    }

    function currentSelector(e){
        setCurrentCase(Number(e.target.value));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAnime();
      }, []);
    
    return(
        <div className="anime">
            {/* Selectors */}
            <ul>
                <li value={0} className={currentCase === 0 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Trending
                </li>
                <li value={1} className={currentCase === 1 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Action
                </li>
                <li value={2} className={currentCase === 2 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Adventure
                </li>
                <li value={3} className={currentCase === 3 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Comedy
                </li>
                <li value={4} className={currentCase === 4 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Drama
                </li>
                <li value={5} className={currentCase === 5 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Magic
                </li>
                <li value={6} className={currentCase === 6 ? "active" : ""} onClick={currentSelector}>
                    Romance
                </li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Anime
```

Or extract the class name logic into a function (defined within your `Anime` component) and call that function for each `li` element:

```js
function getLiClassName(value) {
    if (value === currentCase) {
        return "active";
    }
    return "";
}
```

And use like this:

```js
<li value={0} className={getLiClassName(0)} onClick={currentSelector}>
    Trending
</li>
```

Comment: I was writing a very similar answer, this approach is the way to do it. If you want to simplify the code, instead of extracting a `getLiClassName` function, consider creating an array of the available selectors and using `.map` to generate the `<li>`s. Then you only need to write the case check once anyways :)